# How to make links in FPDF open in new tab

Tags: php, fpdf

Is it possible to open links in new tab in a pdf file using FPDF. I've got a link in the PDF and when it is clicked it redirect into the link specified. But what I want is that when it is clicked it opens in a new tab. How could I do that in FPDF? I've tried styling CSS and using JavaScript but it doesn't work. Also I can't find a documentation about it.

This is my code for generating the link

```
$this->Cell(100,10,$value,1,$ln =0, $align ='', $fill = false, 'http://www.sample.com');
```

Comment: A new tab of what ? The browser ? I don't understand what CSS and Javascript have anything to do with this...

Comment: yeah a new tab in the browser. i just said ive tried css and javascript because some may answer that . and it doesnt work in fpdf

Comment: Once your pdf is generated, it is just a pdf. I don't think it can "chose" to open a link into a new tab of the default browser. That might be some browser settings behind that.

Comment: i see, so this isnt possible?

Comment: ok i see thanks for your answer but if anyone knows please do tell me. I really want to do it open in new tab

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on FPDF, and its for generating PDF.
I think its not possible to open in new tab, you can rather use right click and open in new tab or scroll/middle button of mouse to open in new tab.

Also above situation will arrive only if one is accessing pdf from browser, while if accessing from pdf viewer, it will work fine.

Hope this help you.

Comment: I see. The scenario is just theres already an PDF file open in a browser. and theres a text there that is a clickable link. upon clicking it, i want the url to be open in another tab not on the same tab.

Comment: Mostly that's not possible, still will do some R&D and let you know.

Answer (score -2):

Just do the same as you would for an HTML page or anything else: add a `target="_blank"` to your link or form.

http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q14

Comment: OP requested how to open embedded links inside the PDF